# Avoiding the need for reboots when CPU thermally throttles itself

Tags: linux, cpu, intel, cpu-frequency, temperature

I'm on a Dell laptop with Sandy Bridge Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2620M CPU @ 2.70GHz  CPU
running a  5.15.0-100-generic Linux kernel.
The CPU goes up to 3.4GHz (as both the MATE CPU Frequency Monitor applet shows and as
`/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq` shows) and it seems to get stuck at a lower frequency whenever the temperatures reach a certain threshold.

Then it won't go up to 3.4GHz again unless both the temperature decreases (putting the laptop in the freezer for a bit helps in that regard) and the computer is rebooted.
Is there any way to force it back up without at least the reboot step?

I have my MATE CPU Frequency Monitor set to Performance and I've tried `sudo cpufreq-set -g performance`, and writing `3400000` to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq` (seemed like it could do it) but none work other than both decreasing the temperature (that alone won't make the frequency go back up) and rebooting (that alone doesn't work either unless the temperature is low at the time of reboot).

I care because the lower frequenciese mess up my microbenchmarks.

Comment: Would the *thermald* daemon be running on your system ?

Comment: @MC68020 Yes. I do have a ` /usr/sbin/thermald --systemd --dbus-enable --adaptive` running.

Comment: There is a long history of problems with thermald. (including compatibility pbs with firmware).  Please post its configuration file(s) (etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml.auto or/and /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml). And BTW, I understand you don't want freqs to be lowered when benchmarking but why don't you just disable thermald for the time of your benchmarks then?

Comment: @MC68020 Thanks. I have now tried `sudo systemctl stop thermald` but it doesn't appear to reenable the max frequency. I also no no such config files or similar in my `/etc` but I think that's not the way to go since stopping the deamon doesn't reenable the high frequencies.

Comment: If I understand *"since stopping the deamon doesn't reenable ..."*, I wouldn't expect stopping/killing a "program" to execute "return to defaults" as it last step. Did you try stopping the deamon **before** you had a thermal problem? But kudos for a well written O.P.